# Using intelliJ with gradle OFFLINE for android development

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm going to be going away and will have long periods without internet connection.  I currently use IntelliJ with the android SDK to develop.  When I try to create a project with no internet connection, it gives me a gradle http error.

I did some searching and downloaded the 1.8 zip from groovy's website, but can't get intellij to use it (zipped or unzipped).

I haven't been able to find a good guide to making this work so I'm seeing if anybody here can point me to one.  Thanks a ton in advance

Comment: Gradle itself has an `-offline` switch, but I do not know if there is a spot in Android Studio to toggle that.

Comment: I'm not using AS, I'm using intellJ community edition with the android SDK... if that helps

Comment: Ah, sorry, I glossed over that. Still, since IDEA's Android plugin is a close cousin to Android Studio, you might see if the "Offline mode" checkbox denoted in the one answer exists in the current version of IDEA.

Answer (score 7):

[Android Studio 0.4](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio040released) supports offline mode for Gradle.

[image]

For Groovy question:

Right click on module > Add Framework Support...

[image]

Click on Create...

Choose Groovy distribution location.

[image]

Or create a new Groovy module:

[image]

If you don't have Groovy module listed, make sure you have Groovy plugin enabled.

Comment: That's true, but I have issues importing libraries in AS at the moment (which, if I'm not mistaken, is a known issue).  So for now, I'm using IntelliJ with the SDK  (always preferred it to eclipse)

Comment: So there are two questions in one :-) What's going on with Groovy? What error do you get?

Comment: Gradle 'JourneysEnd' project refresh failed:
            Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-bin.zip

Comment: I'm using it offline right now purposely because I will be without internet and I want to get it working first.  I downloaded that zip file from groovy's website but I can't find how to load it

Comment: Well, the error you are getting is for gradle wrapper. Gradle itself is not included in the AS distribution and gradle wrapper is looking for a way to install Gradle on your workstation.

Comment: I'm not using Android Studio.  I'm using intelliJ community edition with the android SDK.  I download the 1.8 zip from groovy's website, don't know how to get intellij to recognize it

Comment: When I right-click on the module, I don't get that option.  Also, the modules aren't showing in the project window on the left

Comment: Can you create new Groovy module?

Comment: Yes I can.  Just did.  More lost than ever :P

Comment: Did you get any further. I went on a 7 hour coach trip yesteday and foolishly hadnt checked offline mode .... bang... no cached junit (I like to use the mave repo artifacts for concistency), no cached or local gradle android tools. Seems a a poor state of affairs to have to be online.

Answer (score 6):

for the offline-part of the quiestion: AndroidStudio 0.5.2 does not have the checkbox described by @kukido but an inputfield `Gradle Commandline-optionions` where you can enter "--offline".

Alternatively you can ad this to the `settings.gradle` file

```
 // else build may fail because of missing internetconnection
 startParameter.offline=true
```